# How to get data from an URL

Tags: node.js

I am coding my first nodejs module, it's about Star Trek Online API, I want to get the maximum data possible from the server URL, so I've started to search on the internet and the only data available is the status of the server.

The problem is that as it's my first nodejs module I don't know how to retrieve the data from it, if it's possible to give me some advice.

Here is the code I currently have in [my git repo](https://github.com/albator2018/sto-api)

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: 'http://launcher.startrekonline.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/launcher_server_status'
};

var status;

http.get(options, function(resp){
  resp.on('data', function(chunk){
    //do something with chunk
    console.log(chunk);
    //status = chunk
  });
}).on("error", function(e){
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});

exports.status = function(){
  return status;
}
```

The error is :

> Got error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://launcher.startrekonline.com
>   http://launcher.startrekonline.com:80

Comment: thx @marc_s for the correction you gave to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your options to following

```
var options = {
    host: 'launcher.startrekonline.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/launcher_server_status'
};
```

Comment: Thank you @badri now i got a log message saying `<Buffer 75 70>` it needs to be parsed or something to get the message status `up`

Comment: If you are happy with the answer please accept it @albator2018

Comment: I just clicked on the vote, thx, the parse question is another exercise/question